# Ways to investigate why Kafka-stream is in the ERROR state

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Cloud Finchley.RELEASE with RocksDb and Kafka-Streams for production application. 
Sometimes Kafka-Streams go to ERROR state and there is no way to access to store, except of restarting the whole application with removing all Kafka-Streams (don't ask why, it was implemented before).

Do you have some recommendations about:

1. Kafka-Streams troubleshooting;
2. How to get which bad messages broken the internal streams;
3. How to validate and handle such errors;
4. How to do logging when Kafka Streams is broken in run-time;

Appreciate in any comments.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "with cleaning Kafka-Streams" -- however note, that Spring Cloud allow you do keep the application state by disableing the `cleanup` step (I don't use Spring Cloud myself, so I cannot give more detail how to do this, but I know it's possible -- it came up in other SO question as some point). -- For trouble shooting, it's usually helpful to inspect the log files. Also check out: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#failure-and-exception-handling

Comment: I found it: you can do `@Bean public CleanupConfig cleanupConfig() { return new CleanupConfig(false, false); }` -- mentioned on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8153 -- please let me know if this resolve the store issue.

Comment: Interesting reading. Thank you. Probably I've got the main idea. But I need some more best practices how to deal with kafka  using spring cloud

Answer (score 0):

You could use DLQ to handler invalid message.